# Label Studio - What does the "result.startOffset" and "result.endOffset" keys mean in a HTML entity recognition annotation?

Tags: python, label, labeling

I'm trying to import pre-annotated data to Label Studio, but for some reason some of data are not being displayed, even though they do exist.

I managed to create an example where I created 3 annotations for the same piece of HTML, but only one of them are being shown.

Annotation 3 being selected and displayed correctly:

[image]

Annotations 1 and 2 behave incorrectly in the same way:

[image]

The only differences between the way they're represented in the JSON is the **"result.startOffset"**, **"result.endOffset"** and the **xpath**, which is different for the last one (could that be it? I don't know how xpath works).

```
{
            "value": {
              "start": "/p[8]/text()[3]",
              "end": "/p[8]/text()[3]",
              "startOffset": 80,
              "endOffset": 90,
              "text": "25/05/2021",
              "htmllabels": [
                "OIN"
              ]
            },
            "id": "HrCKtUBwJB",
            "from_name": "label",
            "to_name": "text",
            "type": "hypertextlabels"
          },
          {
            "value": {
              "start": "/p[8]/text()[3]",
              "end": "/p[8]/text()[3]",
              "startOffset": 0,
              "endOffset": 10,
              "text": "25/05/2021",
              "htmllabels": [
                "OIN"
              ]
            },
            "id": "ydDDrvEVDC",
            "from_name": "label",
            "to_name": "text",
            "type": "hypertextlabels"
          },
          {
            "value": {
              "start": "/p[8]/text()[2]",
              "end": "/p[8]/text()[2]",
              "startOffset": 130,
              "endOffset": 140,
              "text": "25/05/2021",
              "htmllabels": [
                "OIN"
              ]
            },
            "id": "Fc7iAxUOTX",
            "from_name": "label",
            "to_name": "text",
            "type": "hypertextlabels"
          }
```

My project template configuration is as follows:

```
<View>
  <HyperTextLabels name="label" toName="text">
    <Label value="OIN" background="#ccba4a"/>
  </HyperTextLabels>
  <HyperText name="text" value="$text" valueType="text" saveTextResult="yes"/>
</View>
```

Can anyone figure this one out?

Answer (score 1):

It was as simple as updating Label Studio to version 1.2 (it was on 1.0.2 before).

```sh
pip install -U label-studio
```

Cheers for the Label Studio community on Slack!